# How does DISTINCT work in SQL Server 2008 R2? Are there other options?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, distinct

I am looking to create a statement in which I need two columns from the `SELECT` statement to be distinct.

Here is my current formula below (apologies for the sloppiness).

```
SELECT     team_id_num,
           source_id_num, 
           engineer,
           status
FROM       report central
GROUP BY   engineer
ORDER BY   team_id_num ASC;
```

For `team_id_num` I am wanting to get just one `team_id_num (DISTINCT)`.  The tricky part is that there should be a unique `source_id_num` for each correlating `team_id_num` by engineer (need to group by `engineer` because if not, I will not be able to see the `team_id_num` if another engineer has that `team_id_num.`

Comment: I would like to insert this into a new table to monitor the databases integrity.

Comment: perhaps answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns

Comment: It seems you don't know how SQL work. You want to group by engineer. But what do you want to group? Is there a total to sum? A number of rows to count? And you want to get only one team_id_num, but for what reason you get rid of the others? Do you want a random team_id_num for each engineer?